# Dynamic input data for plot() in MATALAB

Tags: matlab, variables, plot, dynamic

I have text files that contain two columns with numbers. Over a for loop, I store the first and second column as `X(n)` and `Y(n)` respectively (as floats), `n` being the iteration number.
Let's say that I don't know how many files I have and that the length/range of the data is variable.

Is there a way to create a sort of dynamic variable so I can use it as an input to graphically represent the data like

```
plot(dynamic_variable)
```

instead of writing per hand

```
plot(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,...,XN,YN)
```

I know there should be the possibility to interpolate the data (since the files haven't the same length/range) so it is possible to create two matrices, let say `XM` and `YM`, and finally write `(XM,YM)`, where

```
XM = [X1_intrpl X2_intrpl ... XN_intrpl]
YM = [Y1_intrpl Y2_intrpl ... YN_intrpl].
```

Is there a more direct way to do it?

I am far from being an expert: so I would also appreciate any comment and/or criticism on my idea/approach.

Answer (score 0):

The Matlab plot function does not seem to support what you are looking for. I guess you have already checked the documention on the plot command here:
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

What you can do is write your own plot function that takes both matrices as parameters.

In the function you would loop over the pairs in the matrices plotting them using **hold on** to display all the data in one plot.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be reading in each set of X(n) and Y(n) into a cell array such that,

```
X{1} = X1
Y{1} = Y1
...
X{N} = XN
Y{N} = YN
```

Then to plot, rather than trying to merge everything into a single array, you can simply plot each set of X and Y one at a time onto the same figure.

```
%Instead of:
%plot(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,...,XN,YN)
%Use:
figure()
hold on
for i=1:N
    plot(X{i},Y{i})
end
```